# Monitoring SAS loads into SQL

Tags: sas

Quick question, I am super new to the SAS programming language and have been googling my way around. Just wanted to know if it was possible to monitor the loads of SAS, like how we have in SQL - ETL jobs etc. So I was asked to create a polling on the dataset loads in SAS. So once something is done it creates an entry in SQL stating that that dataset is done.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible, but I'm not sure I'm clear enough on what you want.

SAS has a log, which indicates when a load is done and how many rows have been loaded, as well as how long it took.

```
NOTE: The data set WORK.TEST has 10 observations and 4 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
```

You also can add data step commands (if you're using the data step and not PROC SQL) to note in the log when a certain number of rows are loaded, perhaps with a timestamp.

For example:

```
*Create some data to play with;
data load_me;
  do _x = 1 to 1e6;
    output;
  end;
run;

*Pretend we are loading it somewhere;
data load_here;
  set load_me;
  if mod(_n_,100000)=0 then do;  *every 100000th row, put out a line in the log;
    timestamp=datetime();   *current time to ms;
    put "Loaded" +1 _N_ +1 "rows at" +1 timestamp DATETIME21.3;  *the +1s just add some spacing;
  end;
run;
```

If you're using SAS on a SAS server, you have lots of additional tools (though I don't use a SAS server, so I'm not terribly familiar with them).

Comment: Thank you so much. I might have been very vague with the question asked. There is a load that runs on a SAS task scheduler, I need to update a sql table in another server as of when the loads are complete. With SAS Datasets are created, after each dataset is created I need to update my sql table that the load for that dataset has completed.